# How shift left will work

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
.code

main proc 

mov ax,2
shl ax,1
shl ax,2

int 21h

mov ah,4ch
int 21h

main endp 
end main
```

My question is that any other value except 1 in the value of count to left shift is giving invalid instruction operand

Answer (score 2):

In 8086, variable number of bit shifts is done with `shl reg, cl`
Shifting with Imm8 is allowed starting from 80286. See [this](http://web.itu.edu.tr/~aydineb/index_files/instr/sal_shl.html) for allowed addressing modes up to 80486.

Assuming that you intend to use 80386+, you should most likely provide a processor directive to the assembler; such as placing `.386` in the header.

[NASM](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html): `CPU 80386`
[MASM](http://oopweb.com/Assembly/Documents/ArtOfAssembly/Volume/Chapter_8/CH08-1.html#HEADING1-285): `.386`